# How to connect the broken double line?

Tags: tables, line, hhline

I have the following table

[image]

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|ccccccc|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}      & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{}       & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &  & & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &           &      &   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{}                                                                             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}  & 25 & 25 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{25}  & 25      & 25      & 25       \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}      &      &      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}      &           &           &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}  &      &      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}      &           &           &            \\ \hhline{|=======|}
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{}                                                                                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}  & 25 & 25 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{25}  & 25      & 25      & 25       \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}      &      &      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}      &           &           &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}  & 25 & 25 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{25}  & 25      & 25      & 25       \\ \hline
\end{tabular*}
```

How can I connect the missing double line? Expected output is following, red line is to show what I want to do not to color the line with red.

[image]

The [document](https://mirrors.hit.edu.cn/CTAN/macros/latex/required/tools/hhline.pdf) of `hhline` doesn't help much.

Comment: don't use `\hhline{|=======|}` use `\hline\hline`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Double `\hline` miss the [outer border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KKqW.png).

Comment: yes I know. `\hhline` can not span over extracolsep though (even though its very helpful document is wonderful, which is, I am sure, what you meant to write:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leave a comment but thought it might be easier to write an alternative example. BTW, I did not know `hhline` would control *openness* (?) of the double line, which is definitely good detail to know!

Anyway, you could alternatively increase margin inside cells instead of adding extra space between cells. This would also help with a small issue in your table, where cell contents are not centred.

And finally, it's easier to maintain code if you specify vertical lines in column definition rather than repeat `\multicolumn`s in the code. I supposed it adds unnecessary clutter.

Here's the table:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{memoir} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.25cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tbh]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|wc{3mm} | *2{CCC|}}
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{}  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} \\ \hline
    &    &    &    &    &    & \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{} \\ \hline
    & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 \\
    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\
    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hhline{|=======|}
    \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{} \\ \hline
    & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 \\
    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\
    & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

EDIT.
In case this there's an issue with the table not having the full width, there are ways to overcome it, e.g. you could use `tabularx` instead.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I need the table full width, I tried `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|wc{3mm} | *2{CCC|}}`, but it [doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FyYL.png).

Comment: I change `C` in `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|wc{3mm} | *2{XXX|}}` to `X` and add `\newcolumntype{X}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.25cm}}`, it evals as https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQXjj.png. It seems `25` is not centered. Is this expected?

Comment: No. You are not supposed to define `X`; it's already there. Use `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}` and then in the table change `tabularx` definition to  `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|wc{3mm} | *2{CCC|}}`.